# Kafka Consumer Read Committed

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions

I read a lot of documentation about transactions in Kafka but one thing still isn't clear to me.

When I have a producer, producing transactional and non-transactional messages to my topic, will my
consumer (with property read committed) still read in the correct order?

Example for 1 Partition:

1. Producer A producing 3 messages in a transaction
   -> so 3 new uncommitted messages are on the topic
2. Producer A produces 3 non-transactional messages
3. Producer A committing the transaction from 1.

Is my consumer waiting for the transaction from 1. to commit or abort to
follow the right order and after that, read messages from 2.?

The only thing I found is: "Kafka guarantees that a consumer will eventually deliver only non-transactional messages or committed transactional messages. It will withhold messages from open transactions and filter out messages from aborted transactions." but this doesn't answer my question I guess.

Already read Spring Kafka Documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of the consumer depends on its [`isolation.level`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_isolation.level) configuration.

- with `isolation.level=read_uncommitted` (default), the consumer will read the 3 transactional messages as soon as they are produced and then read the 3 non-transactional messages.
- with `isolation.level=read_committed`, the consumer will not read any messages until the transaction including the first 3 messages is committed. Once committed, it will read the 3 transactional messages and then read the 3 non-transactional messages. If the transaction is aborted, it will skip the 3 transactional messages and only read the 3 non-transactional messages.

With `read_committed`, the consumer blocks when it reaches records that are not part of a committed (or aborted) transaction and waits till that transaction completes. Without manually explicitly changing the consumer position, records are always consumed in order.